# Prove if $|f(z)| \leq 1$ and $f(0)=0$ then $|f(z)|\leq |z|$ for all $z$

Tags: complex-analysis

I can't remember the exact problem, but the main point was to prove if $f$ is holomorphic , $|f(z)\leq 1$ for $z\in D$ and $f(0)=0$ then $f(z)\leq |z|$ for all $z \in D$. Hint: consider $g(z)=f(z)/z$

In class we proved Shwartz Lemma, which was similar.

> $|f(z)\leq 1$ for $z\in$ unit disk and $f(0)=0$ and $f'(0)=0$, then $f(z)\leq |z|$ for all $z \in $ the unit disk.

I immediatly noticed that the problem I face, doesn't have $f'(0)=0$ and also the domain is not specified.

Is there a typo in the question? I tried taylor expanding, since the first term in $f(z)$ expansion around $0$ is $0$ I get:

$$f(z)=\sum f^{(n)}(0)(z-0)^n/n!\Rightarrow g(z)=\sum f^{(n)}(0)z^{n-1}/n!$$.

Now the above it true for $z>1$. For the $z\leq 1$ consider unit disk:

Then by ML-Lemma we get $|f(z)/z|\leq 1/r$. As we take $\lim_{r\rightarrow \infty}$ we get the result.

I'm left to show that $g(z)\leq f(z)\leq 1$ and it will follow:

$$|g(z)|=|f(z)/z|\Rightarrow |f(z)\leq |z|$$.

Is my attempt correct?

EDIT: Added picture of question

[image]

Comment: It would be a good idea to check the question first...

Comment: @cello I added a screenshot of the question

Comment: actually this is the Schwarz Lemma, not the one you said at the beginning. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwarz_lemma

Comment: Schwarz Lemma is if the domain is a unit disk, which I use in the proof (kind of)

Comment: Is it possible to generalise the lemma for all $z\in D$ not necesarly $D=$unit disk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $f:D\to D$ is holomorphic with $f(0)=0$, then $f$ has a Taylor expansion in $D$ i.e. $f(z) = \sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n z^n$. Note that $a_0=0$ as $f(0)=0$. Thus,
$$g(z):=\begin{cases}\frac{f(z)}{z} &\text{if } z\neq 0 \\ a_1 &\text{if } z=0\end{cases}$$
is holomorphic in $D$. Also note that $g(z)=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n z^{n-1}$. Due to the maximum principle, for any $r\in(0,1)$, the maximum on the closed ball $\overline{B_r}$ of $g$ is on the boundary of the ball. Thus, $$|g(z)|=\frac{|f(z)|}{|z|}\leq \frac{1}{r}$$ for any $|z|\leq r<1$. Hence, $$f(z)\leq |z|$$ for any $|z|<1$ and by continuity it also holds for any $|z|\leq 1$ which concludes the proof.

Comment: That's the proof if the domain is the unit disk, right? But what if the domain is not a disk? And not unit?

Comment: What statement do you actually want to prove then?

Comment: The first one, which is also in the picture below (at the bottom, where I added an edit)

Comment: But there, $D$ is the disc.

Comment: Does a disk imply unit radius? If so then there is nothing more to prove :)

Comment: What if I take the disk to be $ r=5$, which also a disk?

Comment: Usually, one always denotes the unit disc with $D$. However, the statement is also true for discs with larger radii. This can be seen by just adopting the proof for the uni disc.